# How can I Influence the number of digits when printing a polynomial expression or when I want to make it a String?

Tags: polynomials, printing, rounding, digits

I have an expession (it is the result of Fit) but I want to print or display an abbreviated form with all numbers in it rounded to say 6 decimal digits.

`Print[N[polynomial, 6]]` does not what I want and ToString also has no option to limit the number of digits.

I rather get an expression with `0.0008834432170369743*d` in it (the other coefficients also have physically meaningless digits which I would like to get rid of).

**How can I transform an expression to a string limiting all numerical constants in it to some given number of relevant digits?**

I further want to use such a string for fit in a constuct like this:

> ```
>     Show[{ Graphics[myPlot]
>          , Graphics[{Black
>                      , Text[fit
>                            , {2, 1}
>                            , {-1, 0}
>                            ]
>                      }
>                     ]
>           }
>          ]
> ```

Comment: Perhaps expr = 0.0008834432170369743*d; Map[ If[NumericQ[#], N[Round[#, 10^-6]], #] &, expr, Infinity]

Comment: Why does it have to be a string?

Comment: Carl: I want to show it on a plot. I came across Text for that purpose. But you are right, `Text[fit[d], {1, 2*(h/3)}, {-1, 0}]` would also work, but I can't combine that with an explanation "fit=...". Also the polynomial is no longer sorted by ascending power: in my example the squared term comes first (the coefficient for it is much smaller than the one for the linear term).

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = 0.0008834432170369743*d;

expr /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x, 10.^-6]

(*  0.000883 d  *)
```

However, if the the expression contains exact constants that you wish to retain, compare

```
expr = 0.0008834432170369743*E^(-1.234567890123456789 x) Sin[Pi x/2];

expr /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x, 10.^-6]

(*  0.000883 2.71828^(-1.23457 x) Sin[1.5708 x]  *)

expr /. x_Real :> Round[x, 10.^-6]

(*  0.000883 E^(-1.23457 x) Sin[(π x)/2]  *)
```

Comment: Bob, strangely on my Mma Release 10.1.0.0 (5292910, 2015032401) `Round[0.0008834432170369743, 10.^-6]` yields 0. Is this a bug? `expr /. x_?NumericQ :> Round[x, 10.^-6]` also yields 0. The same holds for your other example.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen - I get the expected result with versions 9.0.1, 10.4.1, and 11.0.1 on a Mac. I don't have v10.1.0 to test on. What OS are you on? Maybe someone else can duplicate the problem you are having.

Comment: Bob, it happened on my Mma at home running on Linux (Xubuntu 14.04).

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen - Only someone with that version and OS can verify the problem with that setup.

Comment: I found my error: I used some package from early Mma4.0 times when there was a Round function with only one parameter. I had overloaded this function with a two parameter version where the second parameter was the exponent at base 10 to round to. That's something completely different to today's 2 parameter version of Round! Sorry for the confusion caused to all others. Now I get your results.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
Text[Row[{"fit = ", RandomReal[1, 3].{1, d, d^2}}], 
FormatType -> StandardForm, BaseStyle -> {PrintPrecision -> 2}]
```

[`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) addresses your need to augment the output with "fit = ". Using [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html) (instead of the default [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html)) changes polynomial ordering. The option [`PrintPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrintPrecision.html) controls how much precision is displayed

Comment: Thank you for your hint. In particular thank you for the explanation because the explanation of Text misses a reference to Row.